# Elastic IP Not Resolving to Private Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, elastic-ip

I have an elastic IP associated with an EC2 instance. The instance is on a VPC that has an igw routing 0.0.0.0/0. Right now I am able to accept connections on my private IP address but nothing when I try to connect to my Elastic IP. What am I missing? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you connect/ssh to your instance using public IP?

Comment: How are you connecting to the private IP address? Do you have VPN?

Comment: No I cannot connect to my instance using SSH on my Elastic IP but I can on my private IP. And no I'm not using VPN.

Comment: How are you connecting to the private IP - from your laptop or another EC2 instance in the same VPC?

Comment: I'm connecting to the private IP from other EC2 instances. They are sitting behind a bastion server.

Comment: The EC2 instance is running in a subnet. Is the internet gateway attached to that subnet? Once igw is attached to the subnet, ensure that your SG is configured properly to allow traffic from your laptop.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion I am not trying to connect from my laptop. I am trying to connect to this host from other hosts in my internal network. I am trying to send mail traffic to these servers, and the elastic IP is associated with a DNS Name. I am able to connect to my instance through its private IP by connecting to the private IP directly, but not through the Elastic IP. I am confused.

Comment: The internet gateway is attached to the subnet.

Comment: This requires the other hosts to have outbound Internet access (either via their own public or Elastic IPs, or -- more likely -- via a NAT Gateway or NAT Instance), and the SG of this host must allow them to connect to it based on their external source IP addresses.  When a machine in VPC connects to another machine's EIP -- even within the same VPC -- that means out to the Internet via the Internet Gateway and right back in via the Internet Gateway.  The connecting machines must have Internet access.  It's hard to really speculate just what you may have missed, given the information provided.

Comment: Hey Michael, based on what you're saying it sounds like I wouldn't even want to do that. That means paying a lot for every connection from my internal network. So I guess I just pass in my private IPs of my relay server to the other instances.